# can't load repo into codeship

Tags: git, bitbucket, codeship

Im trying to set up my codeship project. However, I can't even load my repository. When I click on the name, I get an error (Internal Server Error). The name of the Repository "IS:Like This", the URL ends with "is-like-this.git". The repository is hosted on bitbucket. It has several branches and is a private repository. However, I can load other private repositories into codeship without having any errors. It's just with the repositories that have a ":" in it.

Answer (score 1):

Ahoy Jan,

this is a bug in the way Codeship currently handles BitBucket repositories and especially the way BitBucket allows for completely different project and repository names.

We have filed a bug report and are currently in the process of coming up with a fix. The only way to work around this right now is to rename your project unfortunately.

Best, 
Marko

[Disclaimer] I'm working for Codeship and spoke to Jan via our internal support tool as well. I'm providing this answer here as a reference for other users.